# I have a doubt v. I'm in doubt

Tags: phrase-usage, collocations

I would like to check if my idea is correct. It sounds to me as if the first is when one has a question to be asked, while the second means the person is not sure.

Here are two cases:

1. In a classroom a student raises their hand(The teacher didn't ask anything):

   - I have a doubt. What's ... ?
   - I'm in doubt. What's ....?
2. The teacher asks that same student what is the answer for a question (The student doesn't know it and has nothing to ask):

   - I have a doubt.
   - I'm in doubt.

"I have a doubt" prepares the field for a question to come. That's why we use defined article "a", we know what is our doubt. I'm in doubt means one hasn't got the answer. So answering "I have a doubt" in the 1st case is better while "I'm in doubt" is better in the second.

Comment: Usually, when an ESL speaker says "I have a doubt", they mean "I have a question".  "I have a doubt" suggests that you don't believe what the teacher just said.

Comment: You should probably strike the word *doubt* from your vocabulary, because it does not mean what you seem to think it means in English.

Comment: "I have a doubt" when used to mean "I have a question" is quintessential Indian English. It is not acceptable in British or American English (and I personally wouldn't consider it proper English under any circumstances).

Comment: Using *I have a doubt* to incorrectly mean  *I have a question* is also used by native speakers of Spanish and Italian–and probably of Portuguese and other Romance languages.

Answer (score 10):

In American English, *I have a doubt* is fairly uncommon. It is more common to say the following:

> I doubt that very much.
>
> I have **my doubts**.
>
> I have doubts about the
>   solution.

Using "doubt" as verb is commonplace, as well as using the plural noun "doubts."

As @Deepak commented, *I have a doubt* may be a common phrase in Indian English. As he suggests, you should just use *I have a question* if you're speaking American English. More info here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question

To be *in doubt* suggests a state of mind, implying that the author is doing some thinking and is in an ongoing process of doubting something.

Answer (score 8):

*I have a doubt* does not mean *I have a question*.

If you are *in doubt* about something, it means you are not sure of the answer or solution. Or you doubt the validity of some issue. But in English you do **not** say *I have a doubt...* as a prelude to asking a question. You say *I have a question...* as a prelude to asking a question.

You ask a question relevant to your doubt about some subject. You can say *I'm in doubt about...* as a prelude, if you want. But native English speakers would much more likely say *I'm not sure about...*

In English, we ask questions when we are in doubt, or when we doubt something. In English we don't normally say or think *I have a doubt*.

I know in some cases  this is first language interference, because speakers of Romance languages such as Italian, Spanish, and apparently [Portuguese](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/4167/166321) actually do say (in their language) the equivalent of *I have a doubt*, but this translates poorly to English.

There is an expression, *no doubt about it*, which indicates that one has not a single doubt about some issue.

Comment: I found this: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question